# wpf Image control resize on mouseover

Tags: wpf, image, resize

I found a great example here of how to do this in xaml, but i'm wondering if someone could help me with this example in code. I loop through images and create the Image Control in code and  I'd like to set up something similar to what I found in this link below, so I can have the image resize on mouse over.

[Given a WPF Image control, how can I make it bigger through animation on MouseEnter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176898/given-a-wpf-image-control-how-can-i-make-it-bigger-through-animation-on-mouseent/3176975#3176975)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Data-Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) instead of "looping through images", that way you can completely reuse that XAML.

---

There is a nice sample that showcases Image-DataTemplating:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <XmlDataProvider x:Key="flickrdata" Source="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=flower&amp;lang=en-us&amp;format=rss_200">
          <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
             <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="media" Uri="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"/>
             </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
          </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
       </XmlDataProvider>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
          <Image Width="75" Height="75" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, XPath=media:thumbnail/@url}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="controlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
          <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl
       Width="375"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, Source={StaticResource flickrdata}, XPath=/rss/channel/item}"
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"
       Template="{StaticResource controlTemplate}">
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

This gets image urls from the WEB but you can just bind to an [`ObservableCollection<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which holds the image paths.

Comment: I'm looping through an array of image paths, and opening the images with bitmapimage and creating an Image control to assign too. The image list count is always different, are you saying Data Templating will allow me to do this?

Comment: If you use the right collection, yes. In this case you should use an `ObservableCollection<string>`, if you bind to it and a new image path is added the ItemsControl will automatically create a new image if templated correctly.